# Output evaluation loss after every n-batches instead of epochs with pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

Instead of printing the evaluation loss every epoch I would like to output it after every n-batches.

I have around 150'000 batches per epoch. I would like to output the evaluation loss every 50'000 batches.

Is this even possible? I am using pytorch and a pretrained bert model from huggingface.

My train loop:

```
best_valid_loss = float('inf')
train_losses=[]
valid_losses=[]

for epoch in range(params['epochs']):
     
      print('\n Epoch {:} / {:}'.format(epoch + 1, params['epochs']))
      
      #train model
      train_loss = train(scheduler, optimizer)
      
      #evaluate model
      valid_loss = evaluate()
      
      #save the best model
      if valid_loss < best_valid_loss:
          best_valid_loss = valid_loss
          torch.save(model.state_dict(), model_file)
      
      # append training and validation loss
      train_losses.append(train_loss)
      valid_losses.append(valid_loss)
      
      print(f'\nTraining Loss: {train_loss:.3f}')
      print(f'Validation Loss: {valid_loss:.3f}')
```

Comment: can i see this function `train(scheduler, optimizer)`

Comment: @PrajotKuvalekar sure, I added it in the original post

Comment: @PrajotKuvalekar any thoughts?

Comment: u havnt added the `train(scheduler, optimizer)` @Exa

Answer (score 2):

If you want to skip `n` elements of, for example, some list, you can do this using `enumerate`:

```
n = 50000

for i,epoch in enumerate(some_list):
     if i%n == 0:
     
           print('\n Epoch {:} / {:}'.format(epoch + 1, params['epochs']))
           ...
```

But in your case, you can use only an additional condition:

```
n = 50000

for epoch in range(params['epochs']):
     #train model
     train_loss = train(scheduler, optimizer)
     
     #evaluate model
     valid_loss = evaluate()
  
     #save the best model
     if valid_loss < best_valid_loss:
           best_valid_loss = valid_loss
           torch.save(model.state_dict(), model_file)
  
     # append training and validation loss
     train_losses.append(train_loss)
     valid_losses.append(valid_loss)
  
     ##
     # print every n cycles 
     if epoch%n == 0:
           print('\n Epoch {:} / {:}'.format(epoch + 1, params['epochs']))

           print(f'\nTraining Loss: {train_loss:.3f}')
           print(f'Validation Loss: {valid_loss:.3f}')
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried it on a mini dataset. It seems to just ignore the changes. The evaluation still happens only after an epoch. I have two epochs btw

Comment: If you need to skip printing, you can only apply a condition to the output portion of your code. I have corrected the second example in my answer according to your code.